# ZXing barcode for ANDROID app

Tags: android, zxing

I've code an app to scan barcodes. I've tried to use ZXing and all works fine, but I would use directly camera without external App (like Anobii), there is any way to do this whit ZXing?

Comment: don't understand the question. you want to use the camera to do what ?

Comment: I want use directly camera without choose an external app!!

Comment: like, jsut use the camera ? did you looked android.hardware.Camera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CaptureActivity has the method:

```
public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode)
```

This method decides if will call to an external or internal app, you should comment the following code into switch(source){...}  to avoid exit to external apps.:

```
case NATIVE_APP_INTENT:

case PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK:

    handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
    break;
case ZXING_LINK:

    if (returnUrlTemplate == null) {
        handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
    } else {
        handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
    }
    break;
```

In the next method you can call to your activity, you should comment all and add the next code:

```
private void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult,
        ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {
    String resultString = resultHandler.getDisplayContents().toString();
    if (resultString.startsWith("some"))//define a regular expression in the qr code{
        //do something as call a new activity

    }else{
        //show error message
    }
}
```

Comment: I want use directly camera without choose an external app

Comment: With this you can integrate the zxing reader into your app and perform the actions that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding Flavio's answer you need to look at `com.google.zxing.client.android.camera` package which contains classes for working with android camera